# After waking up Ubuntu (Budgie) shows my user screen for a couple of seconds

Tags: suspend, laptop

I have noticed a strange bug.

Sometimes when I wake up my laptop from suspend it will show me the screen I was viewing before I suspend my laptop for a couple of seconds and then it will ask me for my password.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I use Ubuntu Budgie remix 17.10 but this has been going on from at least 17.04 version.

Comment: Happens to me too on 16.04, but only if I did not lock before suspend. But for me it's only a fraction of a second.

Comment: @RoVo I never lock before suspend I always close my laptop lid

Comment: sometimes it's a fraction of a second sand sometimes it keeps about 10seconds maybe more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300). Unfortunately, you can't do anything about it except reporting it.